# How to separate objects based on column value and retrieve and retrieve the first object of each group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sqlite

I'm fairly new programming and I can't manage to find the answer for a problem I have. I'm using active record, rails and sqlite3 and I have a model called Unit. The units have several columns category, sold, color, etc. and also a product_code that is unique for each unique combination of values from the previous columns mentioned. What I can't do is separate all the units based on the product_code they have and then retrieve and object(first or any) of each kind. The units also need to have false value in the column sold. I first tried:

```
Unit.where(sold:false).select(:product_code).distinct
```

but this only gives me the different codes:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "MONMJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "LAPEJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "ESTXJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "COSGJARD327">,
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "BOLAJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "FUNIJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "CARMJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "MOCEJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "COJGJARD327">, 
#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "RELG">, ...]>
```

The problem is that I need to retrieve the values of the columns for each different group so I can form a table. Then I tried this:

```
Unit.where(sold:false).group(:product_code)
```

This worked fine in development:

```
[#<Unit id: 104, product_code: "BOLAJARD327", sold: false, category_id: 16, remission_id: nil, created_at: "2016-08-23 20:30:13", updated_at: "2016-08-23 20:30:13", fabric_id: 2, color_id: 1, pattern_id: 13, batch_id: nil, profit: nil, date_sold: nil, store_id: nil>, 
#<Unit id: 106, product_code: "CARMJARD327", sold: false, category_id: 11, remission_id: nil, created_at: "2016-08-23 20:30:13", updated_at: "2016-08-23 20:30:13", fabric_id: 2, color_id: 1, pattern_id: 13, batch_id: nil, profit: nil, date_sold: nil, store_id: nil>, etc.]
```

but in development I use PosgresSQL and this generates the ERROR:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "units.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is there a better way to do this selection and retrieve the objects as intended?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the SQL query going into PostgreSQL?

Comment: This is what I could retrieve from heroku logs: : SELECT "units".* FROM "units" GROUP BY "units"."product_code"): LINE 1: SELECT "units".* FROM "units" GROUP BY "units"."product_code

Comment: This query will never work in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL is strict about consistence between selected columns and grouped columns. You can not select all columns and group by only one. Use something like `.select(:product_code)` plus aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do here, but if you want the ActiveRecord relation of unsold Units containing a product code, you can do:

```
Unit.where(sold: false).select(:product_code)
# which returns
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Unit id: nil, product_code: "ESTXJARD327">, #<Unit id: nil, product_code: "BOLAJARD327">]>
```

To then select the first one you could do something like:

```
Unit.where(sold: false).select(:product_code).first
```

If you have multiple Units that have the same `product_code` you can group them together with:

```
Unit.where(sold: false).select(:product_code).group(:product_code)
```

Again, you can select the first entry here by appending `.first`